# 3 Monitors on 1 Card

Tags: graphics-card, display, multiple-monitors

I know it's possible with certain hardware, I have 3 monitors, I wish to run one on VGA, one on DVI and the other on HDMI, however the monitors do not support HDMI output so I was going to use a DVI to HDMI lead to achieve this, would this work ok would I need to buy something to achieve this? The card is an ATI Radeon HD 5400 Series. Any ideas on how to do this?

EDIT: I've reopened the question because the below answer didn't work. I can indeed run all three monitors, however I can only have 2 enabled at any one time. The first monitor is connected directly using a VGA cable, the second is connected via a DVI lead, and the third is connect with a DVI to HDMI lead, all plugging into the same graphics card. The drivers are all up-to-date, and yet it still doesn't work, is there another solution to get them working?

Answer (score 2):

With AMD 5000 series graphics cards, at least one of the 3 monitors must be connected through DisplayPort. A single card can only provide up to 2 traditional (VGA/DVI/HDMI) connections simultaneously. DisplayPort is a different technology that allows more screens to be connected. If none of your monitors have a DisplayPort connection, you will need an active DisplayPort adaptor, such as [one of these](http://www.monoprice.com/products/subdepartment.asp?c_id=104&cp_id=10428#1042801). A passive DP adaptor will not enable your 3rd monitor.

Comment: The card I have doesn't have a DisplayPort input, that's the thing. Now i've booted my machine in Ubuntu and that easily supported all 3 monitors as seperate working spaces, so why won't Windows 7 work?

Comment: I worked with triple monitors in Ubuntu. However, to run 3 monitors in Windows with AMD cards, you need either 2 graphics cards, or an active DisplayPort adaptor, or a monitor with direct DisplayPort connection.  
Taken from AMD's Eyefinity FAQ:  
You can connect up to two non-DisplayPort monitors at one time to an AMD Eyefinity technology-enabled graphics card using non-DisplayPort connections or passive DisplayPort dongles. To enable and drive 3 or more non-DisplayPort monitors at one time, the additional non-DisplayPort monitors must be connected with an active DisplayPort dongle.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this would work. I have a Radeon HD 5480 and i've done this in the past.

edit: In fact, that's what i'm doing right now as it turns out.

Comment: So you didn't need any other hardware etc? Just the monitors, cables and the singular card?

Comment: yes. I currently have 2 on dvi and one on vga. One of the dvi monitors is using an HDMI to DVI cable, 9 feet long one i think. Works fine in linux, so i assume would work fine in windows also.

Answer (score 0):

Colour calibration will be a bit off with analogue vs digital connection, but otherwise your card logic is able to drive 4 screens.

Comment: Both DVI and HDMI are digital signals also, how do you get to 4 being possible - there's 3 ports ? Unless you're counting an onboard card ?

Comment: The motherboard has no onboard VGA etc, so it's literally all graphics card, so I think it's maxxed out at 3.

Comment: I think he miscalculated. 3 at most. At most VGA can do one and and a full DVI can do up to two. One Digital and one Analog.

Comment: A single DVI cable can be wired to drive two monitors, so it is conceivable to have two on one DVI + one HDMI + one VGA.